What's the point in MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING in Media Foundation?
I found MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING in the Sink Writer documentation and it says that it won't limit the number of samples pushed by the application.
I set it to my sink writer and it indeed speed up, only that it eats all my 32GB of memory and grows the pagefile to 60GB and the system is slowed down until I release the sink writer interface.
What's the point in this? Can I somehow use it to an advantage?
What's the meaning to enable it, if, by enabling it, it will take all your memory for caching?

By default, the sink writer's IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample method limits the data rate by blocking the calling thread. MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING could mean the rate of incoming data is not the bottleneck and you need to optimize your code for utilizing the attribute.
